# How to get more restricted google api scope for drive and docs?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-authentication, google-docs-api

Our app has the ability to upload documents from google drive to our app, or to embed google docs in our app.

Currently, we are looking at using these API scopes:

**google docs**:  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly
  "*View your Google Docs documents*"

**google drive**: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
  "*See and download all your Google Drive files*"

However, those scopes give us read access to ALL the user's google drive files and documents.  We actually only want access to the files the user selects themselves to share with us.  Is there a way to only gain access to user selected files, and not all files?  I basically want our scope to be more restricted than those two, both for the user's comfort and privacy, as well as limiting our app potential liability.

I see that this is this scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file 
  "*View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app*"

But I only want read access, and don't need the ability to 'manage' anything on the user's drive.  I also don't see a parallel for google docs.

Any information, solutions, and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some information how the application is authorized to run? Though a consent screen authentication, API key or service account?